# Mongoose Array type data converted into Object (Map with key and value)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have dynamic json (Structure is not defined) which have to stored into db.

Bug is reported on Github as well.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7733

```
let data = {
    "channelTaxonomyList": [
        { "categoryId": "10187", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10237", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10025", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10030", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10157", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10278", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" },
        { "categoryId": "10055", "taxonomyName": "Website Taxonomy" }
    ]
};

let newProduct = new product(data);

newProduct.save(function (err, savedProduct) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err", err)
    } else {
        console.log("savedProduct", savedProduct)
    }
})
```

**Expectation:** 
saved document should like this. **channelTaxonomyList** must be type **Array**

```
{ _id: 5cbefb9d663e872f07f79467,
  channelTaxonomyList: 
   [ { categoryId: '10187', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10237', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10025', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10030', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10157', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10278', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     { categoryId: '10055', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' } ],
  __v: 0 }
```

**Actual Result:**  channelTaxonomyList converted into Object (Map Type with key and value).
Array index changes into key and array elements into values.

```
{ _id: 5cbefb85a09e6a1d4376ebec,
  channelTaxonomyList:
   { '0': { categoryId: '10187', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '1': { categoryId: '10237', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '2': { categoryId: '10025', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '3': { categoryId: '10030', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '4': { categoryId: '10157', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '5': { categoryId: '10278', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' },
     '6': { categoryId: '10055', taxonomyName: 'Website Taxonomy' } },
  __v: 0 }
```

As i describe above the json have no predefined structure, key may be change at run time, So in **schema** i'm using **{ strict: false }**.

My schema and model is :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
}, { strict: false });

ProductSchema.index({ '$**': 'text' });
export default mongoose.model('new_products', ProductSchema);
```

**Node Version:**  8.10.0

**@types/mongoose:**  5.3.24

**mongoose:**  5.4.20

**Note:** Working fine in local machine (OS: Mac- High Sierra).
               Bug is producible on AWS server (OS: Ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS)

Comment: You are notably running through something to transpile the ES6 `import` statement  and similar into CommonJS. Probably babel or similar. Try your listing using standard CommonJS `require` and the like instead and run directly in `node` with no transpile stage. I run this ( as plain JS with no transpile ) on Ubuntu 18.04.2 and it does not reproduce.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm converting type script into js with webpack. So i don't think so i have to change it into pure js.

Comment: I have just check that Node Version installed on ubuntu is 8.15.1

Comment: So **don't run through webpack**. That's my point. Just run the pure form that node actually supports without any transpiler and see if the error reproduces for you. For me **it does not**. This would rule out the transpilation ( and possibly different dependency versions on different platforms ) as being any part of the problem and just leaving it with being `mongoose` alone. Also add `mongoose.set('debug', true)` to your code and show the debug output that appears in the console when running the code within your question.

Comment: Okay, so I have narrowed this down. I see the problem reproducing from `mongoose@5.5.1` and upwards. I think your `package.json` probably has `"mongoose": "^5.4.20"` in it, which does not actually **pin** the version like you might think it does. Remove the caret `^` for an exact representation and clear `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run again after another fresh `npm install`. This is actually a solid reason why you commit `package-lock.json` to source repositories and include this in deployments, since it maintains the same versions everywhere.

Comment: @NeilLunn i had tried with **don't run through webpack** using pure js but still reproducible in Linux. And working fine with Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: I will try with downgrade mongoose version as you mention in last comment.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn its working fine now.